# Array as class member is undefined in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to add an array as a class member in Typescript. But when I try to access it somewhere I get an error that it is undefined. What am missing here?

.html

```
<button id="storePersonBtn">
```

.ts

```
export class App {

    public myArray: Array<Boolean> = [];

    constructor() {
        console.log(this.myArray) //outputs []
        $('#storePersonBtn').click(this.storePerson);
    }

    private storePerson() {
        console.log(this.myArray) //outputs undefined
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is JavaScript's `this` which is bound at the call site. If you write `a.b()` then `this` inside `b` will be set to `a`. But if you do this:

```js
const b = a.b;
b();
```

then `this` inside `b` is unset.

What you should do is this:

```js
.click(() => this.storePerson())
```

This way you call `storePerson` with the proper `this`.